# DateTime Changed Between Requests

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am posting these values from a Win32 Application:

```
      "start_time": "2016-01-24T13:00:00",
      "end_time": "2016-01-25T14:00:00"
```

On the API Controller I am getting this:

```
      "start_time": "2016-01-24T11:00:00Z",
      "end_time": "2016-01-25T12:00:00Z"
```

As you can notice the time is changing for some reason. I am not doing anything except reading it directly from the request body.

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: The `Z` means that it's in UTC format.

Comment: How to remove this and get the values as they are originally sent?

Comment: Use the [DateTime.ToLocalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Are you *actually* `POST`ing those values?  I'm inclined to believe that they're being converted to UTC format before they're actually sent over the wire.

Comment: I am posting these values yes. I can't do the DateTime.ToLocalTime method since I'm directly serializing the received string to a c# object.

Comment: Can you include the content of an HTTP Request (i.e. from [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), or something?)

Comment: The values pasted above are directly from the debugger, would you like to see more data?

Comment: Why would you *not* want the time to be in UTC format?

Comment: Should I just set them as UTC before posting? From the Win32 App?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely printing the StartTime and EndTime in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) instead of the local time zone.